# Changing Mapbox popup based on null values

Tags: javascript, mapbox, popup, mapbox-gl-js

I currently have a popup in Mapbox that displays some properties and a photo. Not all of the points have photos though, so the ones that have a null value in the image link field just show a blank box where the photo would be. I want to set it so that any features that have a null value in this field only show the text in the popup and not the image link part.

[image]

Here's the popup code I have so far:

```
  var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: [0, 0] })
    .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
    .setHTML('<p>' + feature.properties.Name + '<br>' + feature.properties.PopupInfo + '<br> <img src="' + feature.properties.image_link +'" style="width:200px;height:125px;">' + ' </p>')
    .addTo(map);
```

I found this question that seems to address the issue, but I'm fairly new at Javascript, and I'm having trouble understanding how exactly I would implement this in my scenario.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55106852/show-not-null-attributes-in-mapbox-gl-js-popups

Here's the code given in that example:

```
const feature = {
  properties: {
    attr1: 'text',
    attr2: null,
    attr3: 42,
    attr4: null,
    ...
  }
};

const popupContent = Object
  .keys(feature.properties)
  .reduce((acc, property) => {
    const value = feature.properties[property];

    // your condition here
    if (value) {
      acc.push(`${property}: ${value}`);
    }

    return acc;
  }, [])
  .join(', ');

console.log(popupContent) // attr1: text, attr3: 42
```

I think I'd have to replace the .join part with `.concat` and add in the HTML text I want and then pass that back into `.setHTML` in the popup var, but I can't figure out how to pass my properties into this and then how to get it back into the `mapbox.Popup` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use something like:

```
var popupContent = '<p>' + feature.properties.Name + '<br>' + feature.properties.PopupInfo + '<br>'
popupContent += feature.properties.image_link ? '<img src="' + feature.properties.image_link +'" style="width:200px;height:125px;"> </p>' : ' </p>'

var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: [0, 0] })
        .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
        .setHTML(popupContent )
        .addTo(map);
```

What it does, is checks if there is an imagelink property (and that it's not null) and if there isn't simply closes the paragraph.